# Renter starts next year, but advance checks received this year. How to report the income for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, rent

I have a renter who will start occupying my second home in January. He will provide checks for the first and last month in December.

The IRS states that income should be reported in the year that I receive it.

However, the renter has not occupied the house at all this year. In that case, the IRS also states that the house is treated as a second home (because it was rented less than 14 days).

But if I receive the income now, how does that work?

Comment: I'm thinking about this question more carefully, after editing the title, and I'm wondering: Are you concerned more with how/when the income is to be reported, or more with the potential classification of the house as a "second home" (and the resulting deductions)?

Comment: Yes, if it is a second home, and it is not actually rented for any day, I don't think there can be any deductions, even if I spent the whole of December renovating the place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The income should be reported in the year received. It doesn't matter how you define the property (the taxation on renting a second home is different and may not be in your favor, consult a CPA).

Refer to [IRS.gov - Rental Income and Expenses - Real Estate Tax Tips](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/industries/article/0,,id=98895,00.html).  Quote:

> **Advance Rent**
>
> Advance rent is any amount you receive before the period that it
>   covers. Include advance rent in your rental income in the year you
>   receive it regardless of the period covered or the method of
>   accounting you use.

Comment: I know this rule. The question is: How does it work in conjunction with the 14-day rule, which states that if it is rented less than 14 days, you do *not* have to report it?

Comment: @Krish you may not have to report it as schedule E, but you have to report the **income**.

Comment: Are advanced checks actually income received? I would have assumed they aren't income until I take them to the bank and cash/deposit them. Until then, they're just paper - especially if they're post-dated.

Comment: @corsiKa you can assume whatever you want, but since the decision of whether to deposit them or not is yours - from legal perspective you received the money. Whether you cashed them or not is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @littleadv The decision to deposit them is not yours. A check is not valid until the date written on it. At least where I am (in Canada).

Comment: @corsiKa in the US the date on the check has no bearing on its validity, and the OP is in the US.

Comment: @littleadv I lived in the US for 25 years, and for the first 18 of those, the my bank enforced the date on the check (sometimes to my chagrin...) So there are still plenty of places where the date does have a bearing on its validity.

Comment: @corsiKa the *bank* can do whatever, but legally the check is valid regardless of the date written on it and you can sue the person in court if the bank doesn't pay on it. In other countries the check would be **legally** invalid, and thus money wouldn't have been constructively received until that date. But not in the US.